# Resource (resx) lookup returns doesnt return the contents

Tags: .net-core, embedded-resource

I've created a .net core class library that needs to embed external text files. I have added a Resource.resx to the project root and added my text files to the resx. I can now access the text files through code

```
var a = Resource.MyTxtResourceFile
```

The intellisense lets me know that `MyTxtResourceFile` "Looks up a localized string similar to [the correct contents of the file]

When I run the code `Resource.MyTxtResourceFile` actually returns the string

```
directory1\directory2\mytxtresourcefile.txt;System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089;utf-8
```

not the contents of the text file.

The Resource.Designer looks something like this

```
/// <summary>
///    Looks up a localized string similar to [the contents of my text file]
/// </summary>
public static string MyTxtResourceFile {
    get {
        return ResourceManager.GetString("MyTxtResourceFile ", resourceCulture);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Related bug https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/8200

Comment: Related bug https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3695

Comment: did you manage to fix this?

Comment: @user441365 I've just added an answer. hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I no longer add things directly to the resx file. I just include text files in the project and use the `GetManifestResourceStream` method to get the contents, then use a `StreamReader` to turn the stream into a string.

For example, I have a project called `Stamina.World.DataAccess.SqlClient`. There is a file called `ReadAll.sql` in a subfolder `AuthenticationAttempt\Script`. I'd like to get the contents of that file. Here's the code

```
var manifestResourceName = "Stamina.World.DataAccess.SqlClient.AuthenticationAttempt.Script.ReadAll.sql";

var contents = string.Empty;

// this assumes the file is in the current assembly
var currentAssembly = this.GetType().Assembly;

using (var manifestResourceStream = currentAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(manifestResourceName))
{
    if (manifestResourceStream == null)
    {
        // TODO : handle this
    }

    using (var streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(manifestResourceStream))
    {
        contents = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}

// do something with the file contents
```